# VIM switching between split buffers

Tags: vim, split

i tried to split a vim in 2 buffers with 2 different files

```
vim file1.txt 
:sp file2.txt
```

but <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> is not working to switch between them.

giving below error

```
E486: Pattern not found: modification history
```

anyone knows how to help it.

Answer (score 1):

The command to move to the next window is Ctrl-W Ctrl-W; cp. `:help CTRL-W_CTRL-W`. There are several more window commands all starting with Ctrl-W: `:help CTRL-W`.

The `E486` error results from a *search command*, with the previously used search pattern. That should not have been triggered by Ctrl-W, but you may have a plugin or mapping that changed this. Check with

```
:verbose map <C-w>
```

and remap / disable if necessary.

You can also switch windows via `:wincmd w` (followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>), but that's not a practical solution.

Comment: Hi Thanks for answer, if we want to map permanently, we need to change .vimrc, is it not possible to trigger using .profile file. please give me the example

Comment: Hi, please find my map command map ^W /modification history[-:]^[, how to change to enable Ctrl+w

Comment: Where does that one come from? It prevents your use of Ctrl-W commands. Either remap that to a different set of keys, disable it (if it comes from a plugin), or remove (if in your .vimrc).

Comment: i commented that line after that when i tried to use Ctrl+w command it is not working..... do i need to use any remap command ??

Comment: Check again with `:verbose map <C-w>`; you need to restart Vim for the changes to take effect.

Comment: i tried with this command and pressed enter in vim... i got response like this "  <C-W>         /modification history[-:]<Esc>:r! modhist %<Esc>A "

Comment: Then it's still there. Do you use persisted views or sessions? The mapping definition might be contained in there, too.

Comment: yes, it is there also.. i tried in different sessions but it is not working ...